# Twilio Studio Flow - Execution stuck on widget because of incomingRequest event

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

I have Twilio Studio flow and it is calling users, and the execution is getting stuck because the Split Based On widget will not transition even though all conditions and the no condition are connected to widgets. It is showing an event of incomingRequest which I have not seen before.

[image]

Comment: incomingRequest means that the flow has been initaled by a parent flow, which is probably right. I think I need to see more details about the flow to be able to help you. Can you (a) add the definition of the split-widget and also the "Widget & Flow Properties" that you see when you expand a log entry from your screenshot?